# Pyspark collect_list weird behavior

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm encountering what seems to be an odd behavior of the collect_list function.

Here's my code :

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

test = sc.parallelize([("uid1", [{"A":"a_string","B":1,"C":10},{"A":"another_string", "B":2,"C":20}]),
                   ("uid1", [{"A":"another_string","B":0,"C":5}, {"A":"last_string","B":3,"C":3}])])


schema = StructType([StructField("uid", StringType(), False),
                 StructField("an_array", ArrayType(StructType([StructField("A", StringType(), False),
                                                 StructField("B", IntegerType(), False), 
                                                 StructField("C", IntegerType(), False)]), False), False)
                            ])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test, schema= schema)

df.registerTempTable("test_df")

print(sqlContext.sql("SELECT uid, collect_list(an_array) from test_df group by uid").head(1))

df.groupBy("uid").agg(collect_list(col("an_array"))).head(1)
```

I want to aggregate my list of dict into a list of lists of dicts.

If I run the query in Hive I do get what I want. 
But with pyspark I get something really weird with both methods I use :

```
[Row(uid='uid1', _c1=[Row(a='[a_string, 1, 10]', b=['another_string', 2, 20], c=None), Row(a='[another_string, 0, 5]', b=['last_string', 3, 3], c=None)])]
```

The lists get stored on a wrong level.
What's causing this problem ?

Comment: What is your desired output? Show your HIVE query and the output it produces.

Answer (score 1):

I test your code on Spark 2.2 and Spark 2.3.  The result is different from yours, and looks OK.

```
[Row(uid=u'uid1', collect_list(an_array)=[[Row(A=u'a_string', B=1, C=10), Row(A=u'another_string', B=2, C=20)], [Row(A=u'another_string', B=0, C=5), Row(A=u'last_string', B=3, C=3)]])]
```

compared with yours

```
[Row(uid='uid1', _c1=[Row(a='[a_string, 1, 10]', b=['another_string', 2, 20], c=None), Row(a='[another_string, 0, 5]', b=['last_string', 3, 3], c=None)])]
```

Maybe new versions of Spark have fixed the problem.